# Question about class composition of other class

Tags: .net, class-design

Hi
Imagine I have a class of StandardCar which holds a reference to an Engine instance of a class.
Lets say that I'm programming now in the scope of the engine class and I want to access some members of the parent class which means to use some members of the containing class( standard Car)
Can I do it without holding a second reference from each engine to the vehicle it is used in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to somehow make your `Engine` know about the `StandardCar` it's contained in, be it through a reference to the `StandardCar` object itself or through some other data structure that associates the two. But more commonly you'd hold a `StandardCar` reference.

Comment: So this double reference convention is okay I guess

Comment: @Mulder: Yup, it's a common practice.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do it without holding a second reference from each engine to the vehicle it is used in?

Not directly.  The only other option would be if a `Car` is always signaling the action to occur within the `Engine`, it could pass a reference to itself as a parameter in the method.  Otherwise, you'll need a reference to the the `Car` or some shared interface within the engine.